# what is the solution to connect with mongoDB?

Tags: package-management, services, connection, mongodb, statusbar

```
● mongodb.service - LSB: An object/document-oriented database
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mongodb; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-06-18 10:38:30 +0545; 49s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 13464 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mongodb start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

जून 18 10:38:29 ale systemd[1]: Starting LSB: An object/document-oriented database...
जून 18 10:38:29 ale mongodb[13464]:  * Starting database mongodb
जून 18 10:38:30 ale mongodb[13464]:    ...fail!
जून 18 10:38:30 ale systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILU>
जून 18 10:38:30 ale systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
जून 18 10:38:30 ale systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: An object/document-oriented database.
```

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  Your question is also just a paste (*not all devices show the title when the page is opened, so details in title should also exist in your actual question; not just a paste - this isn't a show & tell site*)

Comment: Given the lack of information here, it's unlikely anyone can offer an accurate solution for you. At the moment, it seems connecting is the last of your concerns, as the DB itself is not running. You cannot connect to something that is not running. Check your logs to see what the problem might be and [edit]  your question to include specific details about the failure, as well as the info that guiverc requested.